# How do I enable vertical AutoScroll in a TextView (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, scrollview, android-animation

My project simply contains a textView whose content is a really long text(About 200 lines of text). The user can scroll the text as they read it or simply enable auto-scrolling where they can control the speed of the auto-scroll by a seekBar.

I am not able to accomplish constant auto-scrolling of the text in the textView using a consant speed.

Below is my XML layout

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/autoScrollSwitch"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dance_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

    </ScrollView>
```

I have tried scrolling the scrollView in many different ways like;

```
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom()); // This is too fast and not constant
```

This one:

```
ObjectAnimator animator=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY",targetYScroll );
animator.setDuration(8000);
animator.start();   //This works by acceleration i.e start scrolling slowly before accelerating then starts decelerating towards the end.. I need constant scrolling
```

How should I best achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY", targetYScroll )
//This works by acceleration i.e start scrolling slowly before accelerating 
//then starts decelerating towards the end.. I need constant scrolling
```

IMHO this is good solution. Use [LinearInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LinearInterpolator) for linear scroll speed

```
animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Comment: I have been looking for this for days. Thamks alot @ashakirov